# MySQL Connector not working with table aliases

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm using mysql.connector in python script.
When I'm trying to execute script that has aliases for tables - it cannot be executed and gives error "unknown column 'column_name' in 'field_list'".

Both tables have fields with the same names, so I can't just not use aliases.

Code:

```
query = ("SELECT ti.itemno, ti.active FROM text_item AS ti"
         "INNER JOIN text_itemmember AS tim ON tim.itemno = ti.itemno;")
cursor.execute(query)
```

The same error I get when replace alias "ti" on table name ("text_item").
I can't find any information about connector not working with aliases.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you test your query in any of MySQL editors? Could you also include the schema for the both of the tables?

Comment: @madbitloman Yes, I tested it before using in script. I'll add schema to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space after the table alias, e.g:

```
query = ("SELECT ti.itemno, ti.active FROM text_item AS ti "
         "INNER JOIN text_itemmember AS tim ON tim.itemno = ti.itemno")
cursor.execute(query)
```

Python [combines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) adjacent string literals into one, so you actually have `'tiINNER'` as the alias name.

Comment: Can't believe it was such a small thing. It works now. Thanks!